# Segfault from dict destructor

Tags: python, c++, boost, dictionary, destructor

I have problem with boost python, base object destructor.
When object boost::python::dict is created and destroyed in py_init scope then everything is fine.
But in py_smth scope dict is only created success, after constructor executrion when local dict descructor is 
called then I have segmentation fault.

```
    class py_init
    {
    public:
        py_init::py_init()
        {
              Py_Initialize();
              object main_module = import("__main__");
              main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
              main_namespace["sys"] = import("sys');
              exec("sys.path.insert(0, "/foo/boo"), main_namespace, main_namespace);
        }
    object main_namespace;
    };


    class py_smth
    {
    public:
       py_smth(std::shared_ptr<py_init> py)
       {
             dict local;
       }

};

Backtrace:
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
#0  0x00007f501ddf9a38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002b9545827a38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
#1  0x00002b95450ff12f in boost::python::api::object_base::~object_base() () from libplugin.so
#2  0x00002b95450ff060 in boost::python::api::object::~object() () from libplugin.so
#3  0x00002b9545101198 in boost::python::detail::dict_base::~dict_base() libplugin.so
#4  0x00002b9545101230 in boost::python::dict::~dict() libplugin.so
```

Libs version:
-boost version 1.54
-python 3.4.2

And I don't know why...

Ok. this is sample code which is not working

main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include "smth.h"

using namespace boost::python;

class py_init
{
public:
    py_init()
    {
             Py_Initialize();
             object main_module = import("__main__");
             main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
             main_namespace["sys"] = import("sys");
         main_namespace["time"] = import("time");
         main_namespace["threading"] = import("threading");
             exec("sys.path.insert(0, \"/foo/boo\")", main_namespace, main_namespace);

         exec("def foo():print (\"bla\"); time.sleep(1);" , main_namespace, main_namespace);
         exec("thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)" , main_namespace, main_namespace);
         exec("thread.start()" , main_namespace, main_namespace);
         state = PyEval_SaveThread();
    }
    ~py_init()
    {
          PyEval_RestoreThread(state);
          PyGILState_STATE gstate;
          gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
          exec("thread.join()" , main_namespace, main_namespace);
          PyGILState_Release(gstate);
         std::cout<<"Py_init dest"<<std::endl;
    }

    object main_namespace;
    PyThreadState* state;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<py_init> py(new py_init());
    smth s(py);
    s.print_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

smth.h

```
#ifndef SMTH_H_
#define SMTH_H_

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <memory>
using namespace boost::python;
class py_init;

class smth
{
public:
    smth(std::shared_ptr<py_init> py)
    {
        dict local;
    }
    void print_foo()
    {
        std::cout<<"FOO"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~smth()
    {
        std::cout<<"smth dest"<<std::endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

Backtrace:

```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> #0  0x00007f9c5d787a38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00007f9c5d787a38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
> #1  0x0000000000401a9d in boost::python::api::object_base::~object_base() ()
> #2  0x0000000000401922 in boost::python::api::object::~object() ()
> #3  0x0000000000401b50 in boost::python::detail::dict_base::~dict_base() ()
> #4  0x0000000000401bde in boost::python::dict::~dict() ()
> #5  0x0000000000401c08 in smth::smth(std::shared_ptr<py_init>) ()
> #6  0x0000000000401727 in main ()
```

Compilation:

> g++ -std=c++0x -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c main.cpp -o app.o
>   g++ -std=c++0x app.o -lboost_python3 -lpython3.4m

Comment: Watch SO's syntax highlighting in action, it shows clearly that the code you present there is very misleading. I wonder if that even compiles...

Comment: it's  pseudo code which captures the situations

Comment: That's not even pseudo code and it shouldn't be. And even if it was, do you really think that pseudo code is useful when trying to diagnose a segfault? I don't know about you, but at least *my* pseudocode rarely segfaults.

Comment: I added compiling code. Maybe now you can tell me more :)

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you use `-std=c++11`? Can you reduce this to a single file? Is it necessary to create the `py_init` instance dynamically and pass a `shared_ptr` to the ctor of `smth`? What if you don't create a Python thread?

Comment: with -std=c++11 the same, I need create python threads, and other stuff too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is invoking undefined behavior as the `boost::python::dict` object is being created and destroyed by a thread that does not hold the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) (GIL).  If a thread is doing anything that affects reference counting of python managed object, then it needs to have acquired the GIL.  To resolve this, acquire and release the GIL within the `smth` constructor.

```cpp
smth::smth(std::shared_ptr<py_init> py)
{
  PyGILState_STATE gstate;
  gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Acquire GIL.
  // Use scope to force destruction while GIL is held.
  {
    boost::python::dict local;
  } 
  PyGILState_Release(gstate); // Release GIL.
}
```

It may be worth considering using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes to help manage the GIL.  For example, with the following `gil_lock` class, when a `gil_lock` object is created, the calling thread will acquire the GIL.  When the `gil_lock` object is destructed, it releases the GIL.

```cpp
/// @brief RAII class used to lock and unlock the GIL.
class gil_lock
{
public:
  gil_lock()  { state_ = PyGILState_Ensure(); }
  ~gil_lock() { PyGILState_Release(state_);   }
private:
  PyGILState_STATE state_;
};
```

The `smth` constructor could then be written as:

```cpp
smth::smth(std::shared_ptr<py_init> py)
{
  gil_lock lock;
  boost::python::dict local;
}
```

---

Here is an annotated version of the minimal original code.  It accentuates that the caller does not hold the GIL once `py_init`'s constructor returns.  Thus, both the creation and destruction of the `boost::python::dict` results in undefined behavior.

```cpp
class py_init
{
public:
  py_init()
  {
    Py_Initialize(); // Acquires GIL (1).
    // ... spawn Python thread that will compete for GIL.
    state = PyEval_SaveThread(); // Release GIL (0).
  }

  ~py_init()
  {
    PyEval_RestoreThread(state); // Acquire GIL (1). 
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Acquire GIL (2).
    // ...
    PyGILState_Release(gstate); // Release GIL (1).
  }

  PyThreadState* state;
};    

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<py_init> py(new py_init());
  // GIL not held.
  {
    // Modifying object without GIL; other thread may hold it.
    boost::python::dict local;
  }
} // ~py_init() acquires GIL.
```

In Python 3.4, one can also use [`PyGILState_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?highlight=pygilstate_check#c.PyGILState_Check) function to check if the calling thread holds the GIL.  Per the documentation, it is mainly a helper/diagnostic function.  For earlier versions, one can perform a similar check by directly accessing one of the Python globals:

```cpp
_PyThreadState_Current == PyGILState_GetThisThreadState();
```

The [`PyThreadState_Get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PyThreadState_Get) function cannot be used for this type of diagnostics, as it issues a fatal error if no threads are holding the GIL, which is a valid state.